# using std::vector::erase with const_iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, iterator

I have a function that returns `vector<string>::const_iterator`. When I try to use this return value as the argument to `vector<string>::erase` I get an error that conversion between `const_iterator` and `iterator` is not possible. Is there any way to circumvent this problem without changing the return value type of my function? Thanks!

Comment: Why did you give it a `const_iterator` return type if you want to use it as an `iterator`?

Comment: In C++11 (which you tagged) this should actually be allowed

Comment: @Beta the functions base class defines it as a const function which doesn't allow return of a regular iterator.

Comment: Begging the question. There are ways to get an `iterator` to the same member, maybe even safe ways. My point was that `const`, correctly used, is a *safety feature*, a way to make it difficult to do things that you ought not to do. If you put it there, why not remove it? And if someone else put it there, are you sure you know why?

Comment: thanks, got your point.

Comment: All right then, you've been warned. Do you have access to the container itself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11, both variants of [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) accept `const_iterator`, although this was not the case in earlier revisions of the standard (C++11 §23.3.6.5 [vector.modifiers]). It would appear that you are either (a) not compiling your code as C++11, or (b) using a standard library that hasn't yet been fully updated to C++11.

The workaround is fairly simple: given a `const_iterator ci` that references a member of vector `v`, you can derive the equivalent `iterator` as `v.begin() + (ci - v.begin())`.